# Managing task-killers app programmatically.

Tags: android

My app relies on push notification when app is background or "swiped off". For this reason I need an always-running service that listens to notification and displays them.

Some manufacturers installs by default task-killers app on their devices. Those app sometimes kills my services and blocks the background notifications. That's pretty fine, my application can still work properly, but user will not get the best possible experience.

Most task-killers has a white-list of app that shouldn't be killed. I don't want to hack that and force my app to be white-listed, I'm just trying to find a way to programmatically check if my application will be killed or not and eventually ask user to manully white-list to get the full experience.

I read something about the huawei, or some other manufacturer-specific walkaround. Has anyone discovered a way to do that for all (or most) of the task-killer app?

Comment: Can u provide some examples of applications (task-killers).

Comment: Asus has "auto-start manager", huawei has "protected apps", xiaomi has something called "RAM manager". A famous task killer from the store is "Advanced Task Killer"